# iPhone App: How do they do that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am sure many of you would have seen Jamie's Receipe app. 
In that, they have a shopping list. If you click on an item in the shopping it, it animates and strikes off that item from the list.

I would like to know how do they do that? How can we have such a strike off?

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is the same as in all those "how do they do that?" question.

They've created a custom UIView that does this.

Programming is not just arranging available Interface elements. Sometimes it involves the creation of something new.

EDIT: The strikeouts are indeed only images. You can find strike_out_0.png to strike_out_3.png in the app bundle.

Answer (score 3):

most likely it's just a UIImageView placed on top of the text and then animated.

This has information on how to animate a UIImageView

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html